# C++ Gdiplus Monochrome Pixel Values

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi+

I have a monochrome bitmap. I am using it for collision detection.

```
// creates the monochrome bitmap
bmpTest = new Bitmap(200, 200, PixelFormat1bppIndexed);

// color and get the pixel color at point (x, y)
Color color;
bmpTest->GetPixel(110,110,&color);

// the only method I know of that I can get a 0 or 1 from.
int b = color.GetB();   

// b is 0 when the color is black and 1 when it is not black as desired
```

Is there a faster way of doing this? I can only use it on `Get A R G B()` values. I am using GetB() because any ARGB value is 0 or 1, correctly, but seems messy to me.

Is there a way I can read a byte from a monochrome bitmap returning either a 0 or 1? (is the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `LockBits()` method for faster access:

```
BitmapData bitmapData;
pBitmap->LockBits(&Rect(0,0,pBitmap->GetWidth(), pBitmap->GetHeight()), ImageLockModeWrite, PixelFormat32bppARGB, &bitmapData);

unsigned int *pRawBitmapOrig = (unsigned int*)bitmapData.Scan0;   // for easy access and indexing

unsigned int curColor = pRawBitmapCopy[curY * bitmapData.Stride / 4 + curX];
int b = curColor & 0xff;
int g = (curColor & 0xff00) >> 8;
int r = (curColor & 0xff0000) >> 16;
int a = (curColor & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

Comment: From that, am I able to say: `int n = ...(x, y);` Being able to access a specific pixel at (x, y), and determine if it is a 0 or a 1?

Comment: Use curX, curY to get color data for target pixel. The b variable is the actual color you are interested in.